# Como solucionar um problema de renomear arquivos URL ENCODED?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, encode, utf8-decode

Como solucionar este problema de renomear arquivos URL ENCODED?

Ao converter uma lista de arquivos URL ENCODED através do seguinte código

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
import os, shutil

cwd = os.getcwd()
print('\nCaminho atual:')
print(cwd)

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf')]
print('\nListagem dos arquivos PDF encontrados:')
for arq in files:
    print('\t'+unquote(arq))

for arq in files:
    pathname1 = os.path.join(cwd,arq)
    pathname2 = os.path.join(cwd,unquote(arq))
    shutil.move(pathname1,pathname2)
```

Estou com um problema. Todos os arquivos com nome contendo ":" (dois pontos -- "%3A"), tais como:

```
Security%20without%20Obscurity%3A%20A%20Guide.pdf
Beginning%20Python%20Visualization%3A%20Crafting%20Visual.pdf
```

são truncados simplesmente para:

```
Security without Obscurity
Beginning Python Visualization
```

E sobrescritos com ZERO bytes sobre o arquivo original.
Como a ideia é alterar o nome de URL ENCODED para URL DECODED, este problema tentei contornar com estas linhas adicionais

```
print('\nListagem dos arquivos PDF renomeados:')
for arq in files:
    arq.replace("%3A","-")
    print('\t'+unquote(arq))
```

Mas não obtive sucesso. A função replace parece não funcionar.

**Obs**.: Sei que esta limitação não é problema do python e sim o Sistema Operacional, mesmo assim, o problema persiste.

Comment: qual é o sistema operativo?

Comment: Windows. No entanto eu acredito que achei onde esta o erro. Só foi alterado o valor, mas não passado para apresentar pelo "print" (no código extra do exemplo acima).
Não sei se além dos ":", se existirá outra situação que poderá ocorrer problemas similares.

Answer (score 0):

O código extra deve ser alterado para

```
print('\nListagem dos arquivos PDF renomeados:')
for arq in files:
    ajustado = arq.replace("%3A","-")
    print('\t'+unquote(ajustado))
```

Consequentemente o código original precisa ser alterado para

```
for arq in files:
    pathname1 = os.path.join(cwd,arq)
    pathname2 = os.path.join(cwd,unquote(ajustado))
    shutil.move(pathname1,pathname2)
```